# How to make images max-width = screen-size in element with white-space:nowrap?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a photo slider for touchscreens. Basically I have an element with white-space: nowrap; and inside a varying number of photos and the user can scroll-x to slide photos.

I want each photo not to exceed screen size, but width 100% doesn't work since the container has a variable width.

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: auto;">
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
</div>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: If I understand well, you want your images to be maximally widened? like "fullscreen?" What about the height? Most likely they'll end up distorted at some resize-point.

Comment: No, I want images not to exceed the screen size. So you can always see a complete one on screen.

Comment: I still don't understand. If an image is portrait, than the other one will be partially visible too. You need to post an image for us to see what exactly you need. Or even a fiddle with the issue yould be great.

Comment: You want to force the image size? css : `#divname img {max-width: 100%;}`